# XSD Validation - Either one or both

Tags: xml, xsd

Please find below the XSD I am using. I want at least one or both of the elements : **STYPE1** and **STYPE2** to be present.

Error obtained : Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Here is my xsd :

```html
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="table">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="rows">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:element name="SNO" type="xs:string"/>  
                          <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
                            <xs:element name="STYPE1" type="Type1"/>        
                            <xs:element name="STYPE2" type="Type2"/> 
                          <xs:choice>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  <!-- Start with either A or B followed by 8 characters -->
  <xs:simpleType name="Type1">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="(A|B)([a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
    <xs:length value="9"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  
  <!-- Start with either C or D followed by 6 characters -->
  <xs:simpleType name="Type2">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="(C|D)([a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
    <xs:length value="7"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my xml file :

```html
<root>
  <table>
    <rows>
        <row>
           <SNO>1</SNO>
           <STYPE1>A12345678</STYPE1>
           <STYPE2>C654321</STYPE2>
        </row>   
  <row>
           <SNO>2</SNO>
           <STYPE1>B12345678</STYPE1>
           <STYPE2>D654321</STYPE2>
        </row>        
    </rows>
  </table>
</root>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The schema is invalid because there is an xs:sequence element missing around the SNO element declaration and the xs:choice element.

```
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SNO" type="xs:string"/>       
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
      <xs:element name="STYPE1" type="Type1"/>                        
      <xs:element name="STYPE2" type="Type2"/>  
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The complete schema would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="table">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="rows">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="SNO" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
                            <xs:element name="STYPE1" type="Type1"/>
                            <xs:element name="STYPE2" type="Type2"/>
                          </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!-- Start with either A or B followed by 8 characters -->
  <xs:simpleType name="Type1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(A|B)([a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
      <xs:length value="9"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

<!-- Start with either C or D followed by 6 characters -->
  <xs:simpleType name="Type2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(C|D)([a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
      <xs:length value="7"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact, the XML elements (SNO,STYPE1,STYPE2) can be in any order. If I add the xs:sequence, this will no longer be possible. But without that xs:sequence, as you pointed out, the xs:choice is not working. Any idea how to solve this problem?